# PowerShell - Pass a variable within a variable that has quotes for JSON

Tags: json, powershell, api

I'm working on an API to create a tenant in QRadar. I have this basic script that I'm using and I've ran into essentially the same problem before but now it got a little more complex.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$QRadarIP = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
$authtoken = 'blahblahblah'
$SECHeader = @(
"SEC: $authtoken"
)

$name = 'test4'
$description = 'The fourth test'

$TenantInput = @('{"deleted": false,"description": $description,"event_rate_limit": 0,"flow_rate_limit": 0,"name": $name}')

curl.exe -S -X POST -k -H $SECHeader -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Version: 15.1' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary $TenantInput $tenantURI
```

So the problem I'm running into is that $name and $description are getting passed as literals instead of the value from the variable. The string within the $TenantInput is JSON and those quotes are apparently necessary for the way that the JSON is interpreted. I'm trying to put that variable in the @() because that's what I used to fix my issue of passing the auth token into the SEC header and then into the curl command.

I've looked at other questions on here that were similar but there's always something about the scenario that is different than mine to where I can't decipher it. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
$TenantInput = @("{`"deleted`": false,`"description`": ${description},`"event_rate_limit`": 0,`"flow_rate_limit`": 0,`"name`": ${name}}")
```

You need to use double quotes and define variables in ${}

To understand the quotes in String you can read this blog (with examples): https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/quotes/

Comment: {"http_response":{"code":422,"message":"The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors"},"code":11,"description":"","details":{},"messag
e":"Failed to transform user request body with a content type of \"APPLICATION_JSON\""}

Comment: So it's not registering it as valid JSON format. I did follow the link you provided and that does help a lot. Of course this has now sent me on another quest to figure out why exactly QRadar won't accept that format.

Comment: So I kinda figured out what the issue was with your solution. Your solution definitely worked by letting me put the string in place but the JSON want's that string value to also be encapsulated in quotes so I had to add the `" in front of and after the ${} so instead of ${description} I have `"${description}`" which does put the string in encapsulated between quotes. Now the problem is that when it gets passed to the curl statement it's breaking up the string in quotes and thinking that the word "fourth" from "The fourth test" is actually the URI that I'm trying to send the request to.

Comment: Try to add escaped quotes `" : [...]`"description`": `"${description}`",[...]

Answer (score 0):

So @Damien was right, the final-ish solution came down to me adding those backticks and quotes in front of the variable but also replacing my spaces with underscores soo like below:

```
$name6 = "test5"
$description6 = "The_fifth_test"
$TenantInput = @("{`"deleted`": false,`"description`": `"${description6}`",`"event_rate_limit`": 0,`"flow_rate_limit`": 0,`"name`": `"${name6}`"}")
```

it's definitely a bummer that I have to use the underscores in the string so I'm sure there's still a better answer than what I eventually stopped with.